# Parse a JSON String and display it

Tags: javascript, json, r, d3.js

I am a total D3 beginner (barely experienced in JS). I've the following lines of code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> data ='{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.62,"qsec":16.46,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"_row":"Mazda RX4"},{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.875,"qsec":17.02,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"_row":"Mazda RX4 Wag"}';</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 d3.select("body").append("div").text(JSON.parse(data));
</script>
```

That always produces the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,     test-html:1
```

The data itself is produced via R:

```
<!--begin.rcode results="asis", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE
library(RJSONIO)
  out <- paste("<script type='text/javascript'> data ='", gsub("\\[|\\]", "",jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars[1:2,])), "';</script>", sep="")
  cat(out)
end.rcode-->
```

That leads to the JSON string you found in the first code chunk (data).

Anyone can figure out what the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have two objects there.. My tip would be: paste your json string in any 'online json validator' on the web.. (Google) And it tell you if it valid and where is the problem

Comment: It might be surronded by array

Comment: If you want to see what the `JSON.parse()` returned, you could use a `console.log()` instead of printing it as text. That way you can inspect the object in the JS console of your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `var data` is not a valid Json.
You should add `[]` at the beggining and end.

```
var data ='[{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.62,"qsec":16.46,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"_row":"Mazda RX4"},{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.875,"qsec":17.02,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"_row":"Mazda RX4 Wag"}]';
```

Plus with `JSON.parse(data)` you will have 2 `Objects` in `data` and it's not a string.

Comment: Allright thank you. I got a little confused with all the JSON packages in R (rjson, jsonlite, RJSONIO). All of them seem to handle the json a little differently. I now use `jsonlite::serializeJSON(mtcars[1:2,])`. It delivers a valid JSON object.